# MySQL Select values with two or less words

Tags: mysql

Is there a query where I can select results that are two or less words?

I tried:

```
LIKE '% %'
```

But it returns values of two or more words.

Comment: `like` is a plain substring match. mysql doesn't do ANY parsing inside there for anything other than the `%` and `_` wildcards. if you search for `%foo bar%`, then you'll only ever find records with `foo bar`. If you want to find `foo` and `bar` separately, then you''ll have to `x LIKE '%foo%' and x like '%bar%'`. and at that point, you might as well switch to using a fulltext index.

Comment: Try using 'REGEXP' (with an appropriate pattern).https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
or, you could do `x LIKE '% %' AND x NOT LIKE '% % %'`

Comment: actually, you don't need the LIKE part, if you want two OR LESS words.

Comment: MySQL supports regular expressions in search.  See [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
where column not like '% % %'
```

This assumes that words are separated only by spaces and never by repeating spaces.  If your definition of word is more complex, then you'll probably need regular expressions.

Comment: Tried that, but that just gives you results that don't have three words. So results with one, two, or more than three words appear.

Comment: @JerryCrowley . . . That would be a misinterpretation of what is happening.  Here is a SQL Fiddle, illustrating that this works as intended:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/876a0/1.

Comment: Hm. Ok, I'll take a closer look at my code then. Thanks!

Comment: @JerryCrowley the best way to think of this is "columns with less than two spaces" and the fact that 3+ "word" values have at least two spaces.